# Even with optional variable flag still getting 'result?.expand' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

Tags: typescript, svelte, pocketbase

I'm using PocketBase and Svelte to code a small project. In vscode I am getting error syntax highlighting on this code. It is working and in other discussions it sayd the `result?.expand` should fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this errors are for .winner and .runnerUp , you need to add ? before every . access to make it work

```
result?.expand?.winner?.first_name
result?.expand?.runnerUp?.first_name
```